Why are my inherited Java FX Application class' (App1 extends Application -> App2 extends App1) overwritten functions ignored on launch?
I have a problem regarding Java FX and the implementation of the very weird Application. Let me show it with code:
Imagine a basic Application:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApp extends Application {
    // constructor, ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // important stuff
        initialize();
        // important stuff
        stage.show();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("default");
        // basically abstract
    }

    // and other functions.
}

and it's extension (as is intended):
public class JavaFXAppExtended extends JavaFXApp {
    // constructor, ...

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("extended");
    }
}

Now the calling of JavaFXApp yields no problem to my eye. But when calling JavaFXAppExtended, the @Overwrite is basically ignored and the initialize from the parent class is called. Thereby:
JavaFXApp.main(args);
-> default

JavaFXAppExtended.main(args);
-> default

whereby "extended" was expected.
Why is the initialize from JavaFXAppExtended's parent called instead of the @Overwrite?
Did I miss something important? Is this illegal? Am I not experienced enough? Might this just be a bug? I don't know. But I want to know.

Actually JavaFXAppExtended.main(args) calls the static JavaFXApp.main as there is no main in JavaFXAppExtended. There remains no trace in the calling code to JavaFXAppExtended. Exactly the same code as JavaFXApp.main(args).
There is no inherited this in static functions. Hence JavaFXApp.launch is called.

Thank you. Adding a seperate main to the JavaFXAppExtended is what I missed.

Joop Eggen's answer is correct, but I just want to add some more information.
The launch(String..) method is a convenience overload of launch(Class,String...) for when the JavaFX application class and the main class are one and the same. The class argument is implicitly the caller class. And the caller class is the class in which the caller method is declared. In your question, the caller class is JavaFXApp, because that's where main is declared and it's from main that you call launch.
The JavaFX framework takes the application class and instantiates it for you. Then it calls the init, start, and stop methods according to the documented JavaFX application lifecycle. Thus, in your question, the object that has its start method invoked is an instance of JavaFXApp, not JavaFXAppExtended. In other words, the initialize override isn't being ignored, rather you are calling initialize on a different object than the one you expected.
If you want JavaFXAppExtended to be the application class, then you have two options:

Use launch(Class,String...) to explicitly pass JavaFXAppExtended.class.

Call launch(String..) from a method declared in the JavaFXAppExtended class (this is the solution you chose).


Note it's a little strange to have two concrete implementations of Application in a single project. Perhaps JavaFXApp should be abstract and not contain a main method. Or if which class is used as the application class is determined by some run-time condition, then perhaps it would be better to extract that choice out to a different main class. For example:
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Main {

  // With this approach, neither application class should have a main method.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
      Application.launch(JavaFXAppExtended.class, args);
    } else {
      Application.launch(JavaFXApp.class, args);
    }
  }
}


Some valuable background info indeed. And that it is a bit strange having two applications as such. An abstract application base class is thinkable.
